# How to Send a list in spring webflux Reactive websockets

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

im working with spring websockets , i want to return a list of items from repository

```
 List<Items> nameList = itemsService.getItems ();
```

how can i send this list in a websocket session

```
 public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
        System.out.println (webSocketSession.getId () + "sessionId" );
        List<Items> nameList = itemsService.getItems ();
        Flux<Items> output = Flux.fromIterable (nameList);
        Mono<Void> send = webSocketSession.
                send (output.map ((Items s) -> webSocketSession.binaryMessage (s)));
        return send;
```

this is my handler method how to send the list of items to the websocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Flux<Items> flux = Flux.fromIterable (nameList);
        Flux<WebSocketMessage> webSocketMessageFlux = flux
                .map(itm ->convertIemsToString(itm)).map (item -> webSocketSession.textMessage (item));


        return webSocketSession.send (webSocketMessageFlux);
```

so first i converted the List to flux
then convert it to websocketMessage
then send the websocket message to the seesion where it would be pushed to the clients